# Regular pattern and php search option

Tags: php

This is my sample content.

**aa**jg hgh**a** hdgh**a**gd **abc** jd**cc**jdv dvn**ab**vd **bacc**

I am looking text containing three letters (only one time)  **abc**

So output I am looking is an array with output:

```
[0] = a
[1] = a
[2] = a
[3] = a
[4] = abc
[5] = c
[6] = c
[7] = ab
[8] = bac
[9] = c
```

Code I am trying:

```
$string = "ajg hgha hdghagd abc jdajdv advnabvd bac vdhfdh .";
$pattern = "/abc/";
$search = preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Is there any easy way to do this task?

Comment: Why isn't the first element of the array `[0] = aa`?

Comment: It is because one time a. Also, it will contain only abc. If it contain aa then aa is not inside abc.

Comment: You mean each string in the array can contain each letter at most one time? Because `bac` is not inside `abc`

Comment: I am not talking about string. I am talking about letter.  bac contain b a and c. Also abc contains b a and c

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are expecting. What output do you expect from: `a bc`? Two elements in the array or just one?

Comment: [0] = a   [1]=bc    because there is space between a and bc

Answer (score 0):

Give this regex a try:

```
abc|bac|acb|bca|cab|cba|ab|ba|ac|ca|bc|cb|a|b|c
```

Example:

```
$string = "aajg hgha hdghagd abc jdccjdv dvnabvd bacc .";
$pattern = "/abc|bac|acb|bca|cab|cba|ab|ba|ac|ca|bc|cb|a|b|c/";
$search = preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thank you Marathon55 for your help. But my string is a sample string and my pattern is a sample pattern of letters. So it will not be useful for unique version. Actually I am trying make some cool feature like https://englishact.com/Permutation/index.php

Comment: If you give a more realistic example, we may be able to help you find a better solution.

Comment: Can you explain how these are related to you the problem you posted in your question?

Comment: You will get abc|bac|acb|bca|cab|cba|ab|ba|ac|ca|bc|cb|a|b|c    from  englishact.com/Permutation/index.php     this will be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i'm understanding you correct, but try this pattern:

```
 a[bc]{0,2}|b[ac]{0,2}|c[ab]{0,2}
```